# protobuf vs gRPC

Tags: networking, protocol-buffers, grpc

I try to understand protobuf and gRPC and how I can use both. Could you help me understand the following:

- Considering the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) what is where, for example is Protobuf at layer 4?
- Thinking through a message transfer how is the "flow", what is gRPC doing what protobuf misses?
- If the sender uses protobuf can the server use gRPC or does gRPC add something which only a gRPC client can deliver?
- If gRPC can make synchronous and asynchronous communication possible, Protobuf is just for the marshalling and therefore does not have anything to do with state - true or false?
- Can I use gRPC in a frontend application communicating instead of REST or GraphQL?

I already know - or assume I do - that:

[Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/overview)

- Binary protocol for data interchange
- Designed by Google
- Uses generated "Struct" like description at client and server to un-/-marshall message

[gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/)

- Uses protobuf (v3)
- Again from Google
- Framework for RPC calls
- Makes use of HTTP/2 as well
- Synchronous and asynchronous communication possible

I again assume its an easy question for someone already using the technology. I still would thank you to be patient with me and help me out. I would also be really thankful for any network deep dive of the technologies.

Comment: I feel a need to throw in that [RPC has been around since the 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call), lest someone be mistaken for thinking the idea was first conceived by engineers under Google.

Comment: I assumed that's clear for everyone having a computer science degree? Does my question convey a different image? Should I adjust something?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

*Protocol buffers* is (are?) an Interface Definition Language and serialization library:

- You define your data structures in its IDL i.e. describe the data objects you want to use
- It provides routines to translate your data objects to and from binary, e.g. for writing/reading data from disk

*gRPC* uses the same IDL but adds syntax "rpc" which lets you define Remote Procedure Call method signatures using the Protobuf data structures as data types:

- You define your data structures
- You add your rpc method definitions
- It provides code to serve up and call the method signatures over a network
- You can still serialize the data objects manually with Protobuf if you need to

In answer to the questions:

1. gRPC works at layers 5, 6 and 7. Protobuf works at layer 6.
2. When you say "message transfer", Protobuf is not concerned with the transfer itself. It only works at either end of any data transfer, turning bytes into objects
3. Using gRPC by default means *you are using Protobuf*. You could write your own client that uses Protobuf but not gRPC to interoperate with gRPC, or plugin other serializers to gRPC - but using gRPC would be easier
4. True
5. Yes you can

Comment: Can you please tell me what "Layers" you people are talking about? Please give me link to understand this concept in detail. Thanks.

Comment: Its the OSI model -  added a link in the question. Its debatable whether gRPC belongs at layers 5 & 6 because it uses a layer 7 protocol (`HTTP/2`), but it definitely does the jobs of those layers.

Answer (score 122):

Actually, gRPC and Protobuf are 2 completely different things. Let me simplify:

- gRPC manages the way a client and a server can interact (just like a web client/server with a REST API)
- protobuf is just a serialization/deserialization tool (just like JSON)

gRPC has 2 sides: a server side, and a client side, that is able to dial a server. The server exposes RPCs (ie. functions that you can call remotely). And you have plenty of options there: you can secure the communication (using TLS), add authentication layer (using interceptors), ...

You can use protobuf inside any program, that has no need to be client/server. If you need to exchange data, and want them to be strongly typed, protobuf is a nice option (fast & reliable).

That being said, you can combine both to build a nice client/server sytem: gRPC will be your client/server code, and protobuf your data protocol.

PS: I wrote this [paper](https://medium.com/pantomath/how-we-use-grpc-to-build-a-client-server-system-in-go-dd20045fa1c2) to show how one can build a client/server with gRPC and protobuf using Go, step by step.

Comment: Thank you, this helps me implementing a sample.

Answer (score 18):

**grpc** is a framework build by google and it is used in production projects from google itself and #HyperledgerFabric is built with grpc there are many opensource applications built with grpc

**protobuff** is a data representation like **json** this is also by google in fact they have some thousands of proto file are generated in their production projects

grpc

- gRPC is an open-source framework developed by google
- It allows us to create Request & Response for RPC and handle rest by the framework
- REST is CRUD oriented but grpc is API oriented(no constraints)
- Build on top of HTTP/2
- Provides >>>>> Auth, Loadbalancing, Monitoring, logging
- [HTTP/2]

  - HTTP1.1 has released in 1997 a long time ago
  - HTTP1 opens a new TCP connection to a server at each request
  - It doesn't compress headers
  - NO server push, it just works with Req, Res
  - HTTP2 released in 2015 (SPDY)
  - Supports multiplexing
  - client & server can push messages in parallel over the same TCP connection
  - Greatly reduces latency
  - HTTP2 supports header compression
  - HTTP2 is binary

    - proto buff is binary so it is a great match for HTTP2
- [TYPES]

  - Unary
  - client streaming
  - server streaming
  - Bi directional streaming
  - grpc servers are Async by default
  - grpc clients can be sync or Async

protobuff

- Protocol buffers are language agnostic
- Parsing protocol buffers(binary format) is less CPU intensive
- [Naming]

  - Use camel case for message names
  - underscore_seperated for fields
  - Use camelcase for Enums and CAPITAL_WITH_UNDERSCORE for value names
- [Comments]

  - Support //
  - Support /*   */
- [Advantages]

  - Data is fully Typed
  - Data is fully compressed (less bandwidth usage)
  - Schema(message) is needed to generate code and read the code
  - Documentation can be embedded in the schema
  - Data can be read across any language
  - Schema can evolve any time in a safe manner
  - faster than XML
  - code is generated for you automatically
  - Google invented proto buff, they use 48000 protobuf messages & 12000.proto files
  - Lots of RPC frameworks, including grpc use protocol buffers to exchange data

Comment: Compression does NOT reduce CPU usage.  You have to compress and decompress it to send or use the data in the serialization- which burns CPU _DOING_ that..  What compression does for you is reduce serialized footprint, reducing potential memory pressure, disk usage if used to serialize to disk, or over the wire signalling.

Comment: @Svartalf edited to correct this. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2):

gRPC (google Remote Procedure Call) is a client-server structure.

> Protocol buffers are a language-neutral, platform-neutral extensible mechanism for serializing structured data.

```
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string myname = 1;
}

message HelloResponse {
  string responseMsg = 1;
}
```

Protocol buffer is used to exchange data between gRPC client and gRPC Server. It is a protocol between gRPC client and gRPC Server. Protocol buffer is implemented as a `.proto` file in gRPC project. It defines interface, e.g. `service`, which is provided by server-side and message format  between client and server, and `rpc` methods, which are used by the client to access the server.

Both client and side have the same proto files. (One real example: [envoy xds grpc client side proto files](https://github.com/envoyproxy/java-control-plane/tree/v0.1.35/api/src/main/proto/envoy), [server side proto files](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/v1.24.0/api/envoy).) It means that both the client and server know the interface, message format, and the way that the client accesses services on the server side.

The proto files (e.g. protocol buffer) will be compiled into real language.

> The generated code contains both stub code for clients to use and an abstract interface for servers to implement, both with the method defined in the service.

`service` defined in the proto file (e.g. protocol buffer) will be translated as `abstract class xxxxImplBase` (e.g. interface on the server side).

`newStub()`, which is a synchronous call, is the way to implement a remote procedure call (e.g. `rpc` in the proto file).

And the methods which build request and response messages are also implemented in the generated files.

[image: proto buffer and gRPC 1]

[image: proto buffer and gPRC 2]

I re-implemented simple client and server-side samples based on samples in the official doc. [cpp client](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-cpp-client-sample), [cpp server](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-cpp-server-sample), [java client](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-service-sample-client), [java server](https://github.com/ppdouble/grpc-service-sample-client), [springboot client](https://github.com/ppdouble/springboot-grpc-client-sample), [springboot server](https://github.com/ppdouble/springboot-grpc-server-sample)

Recommended Useful Docs:

[cpp/helloworld/README.md#generating-grpc-code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/chromium-deps/2016-07-19/examples/cpp/helloworld/README.md#generating-grpc-code),

[cpp/basics/#generating-client-and-server-code](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/#generating-client-and-server-code),

[cpp/basics/#defining-the-service](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/#defining-the-service),

[generated-code/#client-stubs](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/generated-code/#client-stubs),

[a blocking/synchronous stub](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/#instantiating-a-stub)

[StreamObserver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.java#L22)

[how-to-use-grpc-with-spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810926/how-to-use-grpc-with-spring-boot/74497898#74497898)

Others: [core-concepts](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/core-concepts/),

[gRPC can use protocol buffers as both its Interface Definition Language (IDL) and as its underlying message interchange format](https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

gRPC is an instantiation of RPC integration style that is based on protobuf serialization library.
There are five integration styles: RPC, File Transfer, MOM, Distributed Objects, and Shared Database.
RMI is another example of instantiation of RPC integration style. There are many others. MQ is an instantiation of MOM integration style. RabbitMQ as well. Oracle database schema is an instantiation of Shared Database integration style. CORBA is an instantiation of Distributed Objects integration style. And so on.
Avro is an example of another (binary) serialization library.

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf is a library that can pack/unpack a structure strings, int, float to a binary buffer with a defined length. This is implemented in many languages like C++, Java, Kotlin and  Python. The easiest way to use Protobuf is to put the binary buffer in a file, then another program can read the file and extract the data.

Protobuf can be compared with XML and JSON, those use a text-buffer while Protobuf has binary data with a length. But any strings can be regarded as binary data with a length. It is claimed that Protobuf uses less bytes than XML/JSON. However, int8 and int16 are not possible and lossless data compression is not used.

GRPC is a communication protocol that ALWAYS works together with Protobuf, it likes the binary buffer and can send it to anybody within the same computer or small network using HTTP2. It is a client-server application that sends messages between one client and one server. When GRPC is used within one computer or a small network, it works perfect. For communication between companies it is not suitable and far from safe. I wonder if GRPC is fast, since it is a very huge program and has many dependencies when you try to compile it yourself. Libraries as abseil make the software even more slow.

Another communication protocol I use is MQQT. This can also be easy used with Protobuf, although I also use it with text strings in Json format. Also MQQT needs a binary data with a length. For MQQT, your message are sent to a broker, then the broker can sent this to many destinations. It is very suitable to use on the internet, since I connect many restaurants on one network. It is used in C, C++, Java, Python and Kotlin. Compared to gRPC it is much smaller.

Comparison:
In software, Protobuf will take most of your time, while GRPC/MQQT just need 20 lines of code.

Compared to the real world:
Protobuf is a truck where you can put all your data.
GRPC is the road from A to B where the truck is driving.
MQQT is a distribution center where 10000 roads can go. The truck is always driving to the distribution center, then to all other locations.
HTTP is the asphalt for the roads of GRPC and MQQT.
For GRPC, trucks can drive in both directions over HTTP/2.
For MQQT, trucks drive in one direction over HTTP, but it's easy to make another road in the other direction.

Answer (score -4):

In simplest form grpc is like a public vechicle.It will exchange data between client and server.

The protocol Buffer is the protocol like your bus ticket,that decides where you should go or shouldn't go.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).